# How to get APS BibTeX style file to work

Tags: bibtex, natbib, revtex

I just started to use BibTeX and have found it amazingly convenient. So far I have tried to use the style file `h-physrev.bst` from [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/), and copied the BibTeX information directly from the site of [inspire](https://inspirehep.net/). It works well since it produced the closest reference style that I wanted. However, I still am facing two problems:

1. The field `archiveprefix` was not handled correctly, I have to manually add arXiv to the field eprint to have the proper output, eg, `arXiv:1001.1001`.
2. In fact, sometimes I don't want to display the `eprint` field.

Since I knew very little about BibTeX so I was really confused by looking at the content of the the bst file. It seems to take an expert to the modify it in order to achieve what I wanted above.

On the other hand, I understood that RevTeX provides certain BibTeX style files that suit the corresponding journals. So I downloaded the RevTeX package, from it I found several style files and used `aipauth4-1.bst` in the place of `h-physrev.bst`. However, I get some really strange results.

I tried to use MiKTeX in windows (and also TeXLive in linux, the later compiles well when I used `h-physrev.bst`), but it doesn't work as desired, I got some uninterpreted TeX markup in the reference section of the resulting `.dvi`/`.pdf` file. To sum up my configurations:

1. MiKTeX in Windows
2. BibTeX style file aipauth4-1.bst
3. BibTeX information are directly from the inspire site
4. I used the following in my LaTeX file head section:

`\documentclass[secnumarabic, graphics,floatfix, nofootinbib,tightenlines,nobibnotes, aps, prl, 12pt]{revtex4}`

5. I use the following to call invoke the BibTeX style file

`\bibliographystyle{h-physrev}`

I would like to know how to get the style file `aipauth4-1.bst` to work?

Comment: If you just started using BibTeX, consider to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will learn to use biblatex, at this stage I just want to get it to work, I cannot even get some style file to work as supposed to be.

Answer (score 6):

For the `aipauth4-1` and related bibliography styles, you should be using the `4-1` version of the documentclass, i.e.. `revtex4-1` instead of `revtex4`.  These new bibliography styles are one of the main features of the `4-1` release.  See [revtex4-1 on ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1).

Here is a minimal working pair of documents:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[secnumarabic, graphics,floatfix,nofootinbib,
tightenlines,nobibnotes,aps,prl,12pt]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\cite{Kapustin:2013hpk}
\cite{Mishra:2008dm}

\bibliographystyle{aipauth4-1}
\bibliography{bibl}

\end{document}
```

with `bibl.bib` containing

```
@article{Kapustin:2013hpk,
      author         = "Kapustin, Anton and Willett, Brian",
      title          = "{Wilson loops in supersymmetric Chern-Simons-matter
                        theories and duality}",
      year           = "2013",
      eprint         = "1302.2164",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-th",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1302.2164;%%",
}

@article{Mishra:2008dm,
      author         = "Mishra, Ananta P. and Mohapatra, Ranjita K. and Saumia,
                        P.S. and Srivastava, Ajit M.",
      title          = "{Using cosmic microwave background radiation analysis
                        tools for flow anisotropies in relativistic heavy-ion
                        collisions}",
      journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
      volume         = "C81",
      pages          = "034903",
      doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevC.81.034903",
      year           = "2010",
      eprint         = "0811.0292",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:0811.0292;%%",
}
```

Compile via

```
latex mainfile
bibtex mainfile
latex mainfile
latex mainfile
```

where you `tex` file is `mainfile.tex`.

As the first entry has no journal infomation, it will generate a warning, but this is the data collected from the inspire site you mention.  It would be better to change this entry to `@misc` instead of `@article` in the bibliography file.

If you don't want the archive information, the simplest thing is to remove the lines `eprint`, `archivePrefix` and `primaryClass` from the `bib` file, but you had probably better tell the reader where the paper can be found, e.g. via `note` field if it is not in a journal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try it out! I was told by APS editor recently that it introduces some problem with those numbers and I was advised to remove them, weird...

Comment: Something was wrong, I copied the head and used my bib file, since your bib file does not contain the journal name but only the eprint number. Using my bib file where the content was copied from inspire site, I got the following...[1]
[1] Mishra, A. P., Mohapatra, R. K., Saumia, P., and Srivastava,
A. M., \bibfield{journal}{\bibinfo{journal}{Phys.Rev.}\}textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{C81}},\\bibinfo{pages}{034903}(\bibinfo{year}{2010}),
arXiv:arXiv:0811.0292[hep-ph] .

Comment: I have updated my answer to include such an example.  Note one must use the correct documentclass; your errer comes from using `revtex4` not `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, since I do not have the style file "aipalpha4-1" (tried google but no easy solution), so I used the one I obtained from the RevTex4.1 package, it seems to work except I got some slight different output as follows (understood as due to the difference of the style files). As I understand from your answer, there is no easy way to switch off a field in the bibtex item if the style file itself decided to have it, so I will manually remove those fields (based on its form of bibtex info from the inspire site) as you suggested. Again, really appreciated!

Comment: [1] Mishra, A. P., Mohapatra, R. K., Saumia, P., and Srivastava, A. M.,
“doibase 10.1103/PhysRevC.81.034903 Phys.Rev. C81, 034903 (2010),
 http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0811.0292 arXiv:arXiv:0811.0292 [hep-ph] .

Comment: Sorry `aipalpha4-1` was a typo, it should be the style you asked for `aipauth4-1`.  Good to hear it helps.

Comment: I have version 4.1r of the revtex package.  I get the output posted above.

Comment: Just a note: if you want some REVTeX features to work (like the ``longbibliography`` option), then you *need* to let the REVTeX class automatically choose the bibliography style by *not* including a ``\bibliographystyle{}`` command in your document.